# Xlookup circular reference solution?

Tags: excel, circular-dependency, xlookup

I have a spreadsheet used for (fantasy football) scheduling and am slowly implementing some automation to make it less painful.

As a result, I'd like to this table of matchups to fill out the name of a matchup that is already entered manually into the table. For example, if cell E2 was manually filled with the name 'Wyatt', then cell E9 would fill with 'Peter L'. Refer to [Matchups Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2XDh.png).

I understand the issue with the current equation in these cells is that they are circular. Cell E2 contains:

`=XLOOKUP($A2,E$2:E$15,$A$2:$A$15)`

...so that the lookup array contains E2. If you refer to the D and F columns, I have a similar equation in place that may not be the best solution, but works for what I need (so far). Cell D2 contains:

```
=IFERROR(IF(XLOOKUP($A2,C$2:C$15,D$2:D$15)=0,"",IF(XLOOKUP($A2,C$2:C$15,D$2:D$15)="W","L",IF(XLOOKUP($A2,C$2:C$15,D$2:D$15)="L","W",""))),"")
```

...which results in cell D2 populating with a 'W' when cell D5 is manually populated with an 'L', and vice versa. I understand this works because the lookup array does not contain the cell where the equation is located.

That all being said; is there a way to make this work, or is there an alternative method that won't result in a circular dependency? p.s. I know this alone won't save a whole lot of time, but it's also about the learning process. Every piece of advice and small problem solved helps! Thank you in advance!

[Full example spreadsheet here.](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AoriZZOgkc1WiL8c1v1UdBcyNXVLcw?e=47iv19)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I follow. You mentioned that you manually enter 'Wyatt' in cell E2.  You also mentioned that the Xlookup formula is in the same cell E2.
I can understand having the result been circular and that shouldn't be an issue if the equation converge to a stable state. However, how can you manually enter a name in a cell where there is a formula? Wouldn't that overwrite the formula?
For the circular reference make they are enabled with a maximum number of iteration that could be '1' in this case.

Comment: Hey Louis! Yes that's correct, entering a name in the cell would overwrite the formula. I am okay with this as the goal is just for all names to be filled out, I don't mind if half of the cells no longer have formulas, as long as they result in the correct name displayed. If you refer to the D and F columns, this is the same situation. If you fill these out, half will have overwritten formulas, and half will still have formulas but all will be filled out with a 'W' or 'L'.

Comment: Understood regarding the manual entry. Now, for the circular reference, does it cause an error?  As per you clarification, writing the value over the formula, is intended. However, it implies that before it is manually overwritten, you would have circular reference.  Personally, I don't have issue with circular reference as I used them very often in state machine.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer that this does not currently work for me. When I manually override the formula and enter in a name, Excel adds a "'" in front of the name, resulting in the formula in the corresponding cell that should change, not doing anything. I believe it does this because of the circular reference, but I'm not sure.

Comment: For the formula in column "D", the lookup value is in column "A" and the lookup range in "C". The return value from column D will provide the result.
Now for the formula in column "E", the lookup value is in column A while the lookup range is in Column "E" where the formula is. The cell containing the result does not include the lookup value and should not be considered a circular reference.

Comment: When you added the name in column "E", a "'" was added, this is simply indicating that the content of the cell is not a formula. However, 'Wyatt <> Wyatt and will not find it. If you change the cell where you added the name to "Text" and remove the "'" you should get the result in E9 as expected.

Comment: The only way, as far as I'm aware, to populate a cell other then the cell where the formula is, would be using a macro or VBA.